# Problema al subir pagina a 000webhost

Tags: php, web

he estado probando la conexion de mi web al host gratuito de 000webhost y me sale un error de conexion a la base de datos cuando intento probarla una vez cargado todo. Obviamente, en mi localhost todo lo puedo ver correctamente, el problema es cuando la subo al host. En mi archivo database simplemente tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$server = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'examen';
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die('Conexión fracasada: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Y el error que obtengo al querer visualizar mi pagina es:

```
Conexión fracasada: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

En caso de cambiar el 127.0.0.1 por localhost el error que obtengo es:

```
Conexión fracasada: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::1b' (using password: NO)
```

He buscado soluciones y no he encontrado algo que me sirva, agradeceria cualquier tipo de ayuda

Comment: ¿Tu hosting es "[Hosting con MySQL y PHP](https://es.000webhost.com/hosting-gratis-mysql)" o "[Hosting PHP Gratis](https://es.000webhost.com/hosting-gratis-php)"?

Comment: Cambia '127.0.0.1' por 'localhost' y dínos cómo te va

Comment: Es hosting con mysql y php y cuando cambio por localhost el error es diferente, ahi lo edité para que puedan verlo

Comment: fijate en el panel de control que te da una conexion para la base de datos, segurametne si colocas esa direccion (que quizas no es el mismo localhost que donde esta el sitio web) funcione...

Comment: Estás seguro que tu nombre de usuario es "root"?  Revisa bien la configuración de tu BD. He trabajado con esa página para hacer pruebas y siempre me cambia el nombre de usuario y el nombre de la base de datos. También te recomiendo añadas una contraseña

Comment: primero no se usa root en el `panel de control -> tools-> database manager` hay puede ver el nombre de la base de datos y el usuario o crear una! saludos!

Comment: @Marcos acabo de revisar mi cuenta de 000webhost, efectivamente cuando creo una base de datos, aunque como nombre de usuario use 'root', automáticamente me asigna un ID quedando por ejemplo así 'id9110505_root'. Lo mismo pasa con el nombre de la base de datos

Comment: Muchas gracias lo pude solucionar con sus comentarios, no me habia dado cuenta de que no tenia el nombre que se asigna en 000webhost!

Comment: @Marcos si gustas puedes añadir una respuesta a tu pregunta, indicándo cómo lograste solucionar el error. Para más información, por favor revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta, dejándola como tal, hay un campo para colocar las respuestas en la parte inferior. Gracias por colaborar con el orden del sitio :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLUCIONADO UNA PARTE]

La respuesta al primer problema es utilizar los campos que te da 000webhosting una vez creada la base de datos y reemplazarla en el codigo de la conexion a la base de datos.

Comment: no olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada , lo puedes hacer el dia siguiente!